# Configure Trello to share subset of cards on a board to certain users

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-cards

We use Trello as a kanban board to manage the work of multiple customer projects within our scrum team.  I would like to be able to give each customer access to the board, but they should only be allowed to see the cards for their projects.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that; people can either see a whole board or none of it. You'll probably have to create a separate board for each client project.

Answer (score 0):

Has any progress been made in this respect?
I too could make good use of this facility. I want to keep my cards on the main board. We could end up with lots of orphaned cards on multiple client boards which seems counter intuitive to keeping things simple to monitor.

I see a clone bot was proposed in this thread [Making a template card in Trello that will automatically update all its 'clones' if changed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58723/making-a-template-card-in-trello-that-will-automatically-update-all-its-clones?rq=1)
Unfortunately the link seems dead.

A cloned or mirrored card seems a great idea, the clone is sandboxed for restricted external collaboration and the master gets updated on the secure board.
Is anything along these lines on the horizon? I see a roadmap board but can't access the old development suggestion board, - has that been taken offline?