# Making a template card in Trello that will automatically update all its 'clones' if changed

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-organization, trello-boards

I'm using a Trello board to manage an application workflow, I've got multiple columns for each stage of the process, but so that I don't end up with hundreds of columns I use checklists to break down each card that I go through before moving them onto the next column.

I made a template card which had all the checklists in it and then I copied this for each applicant.

Now I want to add in another checklist into the cards but is there a way I can get it to update all the other cards that were made / copied from the master ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [@cardsync](https://trello.com/cardsync), a Trello bot that I wrote that does exactly this: keeps cards in sync.

From the bot's own description:

> You can use me to create 2 or more twin cards in 2 or more boards. Whenever someone updates the name, description, due date, cover image, checklists and checkitem states, add or remove attachments or add, delete or edit comments in some card, I will perform the same changes in the synced cards.

And a quick animation showing it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly that isn't possible.

Well, I mean, it's possible to write a script to do that with the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/), but it's not possible through the Trello web app.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in littlebluemonkey solution described in his blogpost: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/add-enhanced-workflow-to-trello.
I think it may eaxctly do what you want.
It is implemented as a Google script.