# Moving from internal Trello work board to external client Trello board

Tags: trello

We use Trello in our office for keeping track of projects etc and it proves very useful.

However, we only use it internally. After engaging in about 100 emails with a client over a week it has prompted me to possibly setup a 2nd client external board. Where both myself and clients can add/edit lists and cards.

Is there a way you can do this, but only restrict access for the client to a specific list including its cards. But obviously we would want clients to access or use other lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Trello to share subset of cards on a board to certain users](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44166/configure-trello-to-share-subset-of-cards-on-a-board-to-certain-users)

Answer (score 2):

There are no per-list permissions in Trello at the moment. The best solution would be to create a board for each client. This has the advantage that if the communication with the client gets more complicated,  you can structure the conversation by having multiple lists in the board.